I have a rabbitmq service in aws ec2 and i have attached an Route 53 record for it but when i am giving the record in code instead of ip getting error
AMQP Exception 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
I have treied connexting through python and dotnet but sadly wasnt reachable for any of it.
I have tried doing some changes in my rabbitmq config file as suggested ny some portals and chatgpt but nothing works

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
